# Thunderbird portable

Tags: thunderbird, portable

Just transferred from Windows to Ubuntu and I am looking for a Mozilla Thunderbird Portable version for linux.

All I could find is this:

https://portableapps.com/node/16344

Now I made that script, executed it, and got an empty folder with another script in it.
What do I have to do with this in order to get a Thunderbird Portable? I am a complete novice in Linux, sorry for my ignorance in advance!

Comment: There is an AppImage for Thunderbird here that I have just now tested: https://www.appimagehub.com/p/1169215/ Is something like this what you are after?

Comment: I have already installed Thunderbird using a terminal - sudo apt install thunderbird

I guess this is the same app; What I am looking for is a portable version of this application

Comment: What sort of portability are you after?

Comment: Like on windows, so that everything would be contained in a single directory, and I could just take that dir with me on my other machine or system when needed :)

Comment: The AppImage that I have given will do this but remember that if on a USB this AppImage will still only operate in a Linux environment. The AppImage is a single file with all dependencies compiled in... For Windows I see this: https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable

Answer (score -1):

To install Thunderbird, you can open the terminal and type `sudo apt install thunderbird`. This will install Thunderbird onto your computer. If at anytime you want to uninstall it. You can just type `sudo apt remove thunderbird`. You should not need a portable version.

Comment: I have already done that; I am looking for a portable solution :)